# Mouse 1 doesn't follow footnote in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

I define a footnote via :  <kbd>C-c  C-x f</kbd>  as described in the [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Footnotes.html).
Then I have something like:

```
Leo once said [fn:1]  (reference)
..
..
..
* Footnotes 
  [fn:1] To make the world a better place, one should use Emacs. (definition)
```

Now clicking on the definition `[fn:1] To make ..` jumps back to the reference.
But clicking on the reference doesn't jump me to the definition.

Jumping from reference to the definition still works via <kbd>C-c  C-c</kbd>, but id'd be nice to have Mouse-1 support.

Is this just me or is this the case for everyone out there? If so, is there a way to make it jump to definition when clicking the reference?

I'm using emacs 24.4.1 btw. If it makes a difference, I use org-mouse also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. It turns out org-mouse is the culprit. I've sent an email to the org mailing list about it.